# Как разместить программно GameObjects и сменить текстуру

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю виртуальный тур по дому.
http://iscr.ru/image/voTvf
Для каждой квартиры есть свои текстуры. Соответственно, hotpoint для перехода будут находится на разных позициях.

Как лучше реализовать смену текстур и хотпоинтов для каждой комнаты?

Comment: Что ты хочешь получить от этого "Как лучше реализовать" ? Какие критерии тебе нужны? не дублировать комнаты, не держать много текстур в памяти и т.д. ?

Comment: По идее должно работать все так: по клику мышки на нужную квартиру на сферы подгружаются нужные текстуры с нужными хотпоинтами и т.д. У каждой квартиры свой id. Я планирую хранить позиции всех хотпоинтов в json и потом по id их находить и размещать. над текстурами еще не думал.

Comment: А префабы на что?

Comment: Да) спасибо) что-то не подумал)